# Is there a was to wrap text in a ir column

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

i have an ir report which has a comment field. The comments can be very long is there a way to wrap text in the ir report column??

Answer (score 0):

I go through .. Changed the interactive report to a classic report and in the field name which is 'comments' inserted

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
p.test {
  width: 11em; 
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



<p class="test"> #COMMENTS#.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

under HTML Expression

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish:

1. Go to the IR report
2. Go to Column Attributes
3. Select the pencil icon of the column you want to be wrap text
4. Locate: Column Formatting >> HTML Expression
5. Add code: `<div style="white-space:normal;">#DESCRIPTION#</div>`

NOTE: Replace "DESCRIPTION" with your column name.

That should do the trick.